# How to print the memory address and the value of the arguments of a C/C++ function that is being debugged with LLDB?

Tags: c++, c, xcode, debugging, lldb

I'm getting ready for my OS test. One of the tools we use is the debugger(LLDB) and my goal is to inspect the arguments of a C function or a C++ method.

For instance: How may I see the memory address and the value of the arguments passed to _SMenuItemCommandID?? - I have tried different things, but died in the attempt.

```
HITestBox`_SMenuItemCommandID(MenuData*, unsigned short, unsigned long):
0x9a7bfc35:  pushl  %ebp
0x9a7bfc36:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x9a7bfc38:  pushl  %esi
0x9a7bfc39:  subl   $52, %esp
0x9a7bfc3c:  movl   8(%ebp), %esi
0x9a7bfc3f:  movl   88(%esi), %eax
0x9a7bfc42:  movl   %eax, -16(%ebp)
0x9a7bfc45:  movzwl 12(%ebp), %ecx
0x9a7bfc49:  movw   %cx, -12(%ebp)
0x9a7bfc4d:  movl   $0, -8(%ebp)
0x9a7bfc54:  leal   -8(%ebp), %edx
0x9a7bfc57:  movl   %edx, 28(%esp)
0x9a7bfc5b:  movl   %ecx, 4(%esp)
0x9a7bfc5f:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x9a7bfc62:  movl   $0, 24(%esp)
0x9a7bfc6a:  movl   $4, 20(%esp)
0x9a7bfc72:  movl   $0, 16(%esp)
0x9a7bfc7a:  movl   $1835232612, 12(%esp)
0x9a7bfc82:  movl   $12, 8(%esp)
0x9a7bfc8a:  calll  0x9a5f7c9b                ; elementGetDataAtIndex
0x9a7bfc8f:  movl   16(%ebp), %eax
0x9a7bfc92:  cmpl   %eax, -8(%ebp)
0x9a7bfc95:  je     0x9a7bfcae                ; _SMenuItemCommandID(MenuData*, unsigned short, unsigned long) + 121
0x9a7bfc97:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x9a7bfc9b:  leal   -16(%ebp), %eax
0x9a7bfc9e:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x9a7bfca1:  calll  0x9a7e2914                ; mID::SetCommandID(unsigned long)
0x9a7bfca6:  movl   %esi, (%esp)
0x9a7bfca9:  calll  0x9a5f7c65                ; invalidate(MenuData*)
0x9a7bfcae:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x9a7bfcb0:  addl   $52, %esp
0x9a7bfcb3:  popl   %esi
0x9a7bfcb4:  popl   %ebp
0x9a7bfcb5:  ret
```

Edit:
Say I'm debugging an app which I don't have the source code, but I have the symbols exported.
Say, at some moment this code gets executed:

```
MenuData *myData = (MenuData *)0x28ff44;;
SMenuItemCommandID(myData, 3, 4);
```

What do I need to do (with LLDB) to get:

```
arg0 = 0x28ff44   
arg1 =3  
arg2 =4
```

Comment: Are you using lldb from XCode or from the command-line?

Comment: You should be able to set a breakpoint on the function and step through - it will show you all that.

Comment: That works if I have the code of the inspected app. But, what if I'm debugging an app that I don't have the source code for? (for instance, this is a test app from our teacher, it has symbols exported).

Comment: It works the same way... In terminal (eg. lldb some.app), then set a breakpoint on the function or offset.

Comment: Right. I see 3 groups (Exception State Registers, Floating point registers, general purpose registers). But still, no idea how to get the arguments value. (I updated my question to reflect what I really want).
Thanks!

Comment: Using `frame variable` should show you the args; sometimes it doesn't and you need to find the pointer, which you can generally get from register read --all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disassembly that you posted is x86. The arguments are on the stack. If you break before the function prolog, the arguments are relative to the stack pointer, `%esp` (which is accessed as `$esp` in `lldb`):

```
# The return address:
x/w $esp
# The first argument:
x/w $esp+4
# The second argument:
x/w $esp+8
```

If you break after the prolog (`0x9a7bfc3c` in your example), which is where symbolic breakpoints are usually placed, the arguments are found relative to the frame pointer (`%ebp` a.k.a. `$ebp`):

```
# The saved frame pointer of the previous frame:
x/w $ebp
# The return address:
x/w $ebp+4
# The first argument:
x/w $ebp+8
# The second argument:
x/w $ebp+12
```

For other architectures, the arguments will be stored differently, often in the registers. Also, the above assumes the "cdecl" calling convention. There are others. Have you been told which architecture(s) and calling convention(s) you're expected to be familiar with?

Comment: Architecture: 32bits, calling convention: x86